# aiohttp: rate limiting parallel requests

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-asyncio, aiohttp

APIs often have rate limits that users have to follow. As an example let's take 50 requests/second. Sequential requests take 0.5-1 second and thus are too slow to come close to that limit. Parallel requests with aiohttp, however, exceed the rate limit.

To poll the API as fast as allowed, one needs to rate limit parallel calls.

Examples that I found so far decorate `session.get`, approximately like so:

```
session.get = rate_limited(max_calls_per_second)(session.get)
```

This works well for sequential calls. Trying to implement this in parallel calls does not work as intended.

Here's some code as example:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    session.get = rate_limited(max_calls_per_second)(session.get)
    tasks = (asyncio.ensure_future(download_coroutine(  
          timeout, session, url)) for url in urls)
    process_responses_function(await asyncio.gather(*tasks))
```

The problem with this is that it will rate-limit the **queueing** of the tasks. The execution with `gather` will still happen more or less at the same time. Worst of both worlds ;-).

Yes, I found a similar question right here [aiohttp: set maximum number of requests per second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196974/aiohttp-set-maximum-number-of-requests-per-second), but neither replies answer the actual question of limiting the rate of requests. Also [the blog post from Quentin Pradet](https://quentin.pradet.me/blog/how-do-you-rate-limit-calls-with-aiohttp.html) works only on rate-limiting the queueing.

To wrap it up: How can one limit the *number of requests per second* for parallel `aiohttp` requests?

Comment: Related question can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196974/aiohttp-set-maximum-number-of-requests-per-second/35198369

Comment: @user1929959 Yes, as mentioned in my post. Unfortunately that question was not answered correctly. The replies talk about limiting the number of simultaneous requests. What was asked was the number of requests per second.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If I understand you well, you want to limit the number of simultaneous requests?

There is a object inside `asyncio` named `Semaphore`, it works like an asynchronous `RLock`.

```
semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(50)
#...
async def limit_wrap(url):
    async with semaphore:
        # do what you want
#...
results = asyncio.gather([limit_wrap(url) for url in urls])
```

## updated

Suppose I make 50 concurrent requests, and they all finish in 2 seconds. So, it doesn't touch the limitation(only 25 requests per seconds).

That means I should make 100 concurrent requests, and they all finish in 2 seconds too(50 requests per seconds). But before you actually make those requests, how could you determine how long will they finish?

Or if you doesn't mind **finished requests per second** but **requests made per second**. You can:

```
async def loop_wrap(urls):
    for url in urls:
        asyncio.ensure_future(download(url))
        await asyncio.sleep(1/50)

asyncio.ensure_future(loop_wrap(urls))
loop.run_forever()
```

The code above will create a `Future` instance every `1/50` second.

Comment: No, it's about limiting the number of __requests per second__, how many times per second you send a request. The number of simultaneous requests depends on how long these requests take, but the API we want to use does not limit that.

Comment: @Boffin It's impossible. First you need to make those requests, then you can get how much time those cost. What you want is to foresee. For example, at first I make 50 concurrent requests, how could I determine whether they will be finished in one second?

Comment: How long the requests take is not relevant. I want to launch another request 1/50 seconds after the previous one. The requests take (let's say) 1 second, so several have to be on the way at the same time. How many are running simultaneously, however, is not important. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @Boffin Updated, hope it is helpful.

Comment: The updated code seems equivalent to `for url in urls: await asyncio.sleep(1/50); await download_coroutine(url)`

Comment: @user4815162342 No, it doesn't. As `for` is synchronous, and `await download_coroutine(url)` will block current `for` loop until `download_coroutine` finish. In this case, there is no difference to make requests just one by one. But it can be changed into `for url in urls: await asyncio.sleep(1/50); asyncio.ensure_future(download_coroutine(url))`. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: You're right. The difference is that you want to *start* a new download every 1/50 s, and keep it running "in the background". The loop should probably collect the tasks into a list and return them, so they can be either `gather`ed or cancelled, otherwise asyncio will complain when the loop is destroyed.

Comment: My apologies for the late reply @Sraw , your update works as intended. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @Sraw, can you help with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55562210/python-multiple-parallel-aiohttp-websocket-requests - It's a very similar problem.

Answer (score 19):

I approached the problem by creating a subclass of `aiohttp.ClientSession()` with a ratelimiter based on the leaky-bucket algorithm. I use `asyncio.Queue()` for ratelimiting instead of `Semaphores`. I’ve only overridden the `_request()` method. I find this approach cleaner since you only replace `session = aiohttp.ClientSession()` with `session = ThrottledClientSession(rate_limit=15)`.

```py
class ThrottledClientSession(aiohttp.ClientSession):
    """
    Rate-throttled client session class inherited from aiohttp.ClientSession)

    USAGE:
        replace `session = aiohttp.ClientSession()`
        with `session = ThrottledClientSession(rate_limit=15)`

    see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60357775/107049
    """

    MIN_SLEEP = 0.1

    def __init__(self, rate_limit: float = None, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.rate_limit = rate_limit
        self._fillerTask = None
        self._queue = None
        self._start_time = time.time()
        if rate_limit is not None:
            if rate_limit <= 0:
                raise ValueError('rate_limit must be positive')
            self._queue = asyncio.Queue(min(2, int(rate_limit) + 1))
            self._fillerTask = asyncio.create_task(self._filler(rate_limit))

    def _get_sleep(self) -> Optional[float]:
        if self.rate_limit is not None:
            return max(1 / self.rate_limit, self.MIN_SLEEP)
        return None

    async def close(self) -> None:
        """Close rate-limiter's "bucket filler" task"""
        if self._fillerTask is not None:
            self._fillerTask.cancel()
        try:
            await asyncio.wait_for(self._fillerTask, timeout=0.5)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError as err:
            print(str(err))
        await super().close()

    async def _filler(self, rate_limit: float = 1):
        """Filler task to fill the leaky bucket algo"""
        try:
            if self._queue is None:
                return
            self.rate_limit = rate_limit
            sleep = self._get_sleep()
            updated_at = time.monotonic()
            fraction = 0
            extra_increment = 0
            for i in range(0, self._queue.maxsize):
                self._queue.put_nowait(i)
            while True:
                if not self._queue.full():
                    now = time.monotonic()
                    increment = rate_limit * (now - updated_at)
                    fraction += increment % 1
                    extra_increment = fraction // 1
                    items_2_add = int(min(self._queue.maxsize - self._queue.qsize(), int(increment) + extra_increment))
                    fraction = fraction % 1
                    for i in range(0, items_2_add):
                        self._queue.put_nowait(i)
                    updated_at = now
                await asyncio.sleep(sleep)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print('Cancelled')
        except Exception as err:
            print(str(err))

    async def _allow(self) -> None:
        if self._queue is not None:
            # debug
            # if self._start_time == None:
            #    self._start_time = time.time()
            await self._queue.get()
            self._queue.task_done()
        return None

    async def _request(self, *args, **kwargs)  -> aiohttp.ClientResponse:
        """Throttled _request()"""
        await self._allow()
        return await super()._request(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: How do you make this subclass accessible? When I  placed this into my main script I get the error: `AttributeError: module 'aiohttp' has no attribute 'ThrottledClientSession'`

Comment: Hi, the new subclass won’t be part of aiohttp package. Either your add the class to the same source file or then you import it: ‘import ThrottledClientSession from filename_of_the_class_source_file’

Comment: You can find the latest version from here: https://github.com/Jylpah/blitz-tools/blob/master/blitzutils.py

Comment: Saved as blitzutils.py in the working directory and placed `import ThrottledClientSession from blitzutils` in the script but I got an error. I think you meant `from blitzutils import ThrottledClientSession`

Comment: Somebody else agreed with this solution and wrote a package https://aiolimiter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I get a deprecation warning, anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: @thatrandomperson, if you are referring to my `ThrottledClientSession()`, I have moved it to a new repo https://github.com/Jylpah/pyutils. 
See: https://github.com/Jylpah/pyutils/blob/main/throttledclientsession.py

Answer (score 4):

I liked @sraw's approached this with asyncio, but their answer didn't quite cut it for me. Since I don't know if my calls to download are going to each be faster or slower than the rate limit I want to have the option to run many in parallel when requests are slow and run one at a time when requests are very fast so that I'm always right at the rate limit.

I do this by using a queue with a producer that produces new tasks at the rate limit, then many consumers that will either all wait on the next job if they're fast, or there will be work backed up in the queue if they are slow, and will run as fast as the processor/network allow:

```py
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime 

async def download(url):
  # download or whatever
  task_time = 1/10
  await asyncio.sleep(task_time)
  result = datetime.now()
  return result, url

async def producer_fn(queue, urls, max_per_second):
  for url in urls:
    await queue.put(url)
    await asyncio.sleep(1/max_per_second)
 
async def consumer(work_queue, result_queue):
  while True:
    url = await work_queue.get()
    result = await download(url)
    work_queue.task_done()
    await result_queue.put(result)

urls = range(20)
async def main():
  work_queue = asyncio.Queue()
  result_queue = asyncio.Queue()

  num_consumer_tasks = 10
  max_per_second = 5
  consumers = [asyncio.create_task(consumer(work_queue, result_queue))
               for _ in range(num_consumer_tasks)]    
  producer = asyncio.create_task(producer_fn(work_queue, urls, max_per_second))
  await producer

  # wait for the remaining tasks to be processed
  await work_queue.join()
  # cancel the consumers, which are now idle
  for c in consumers:
    c.cancel()

  while not result_queue.empty():
    result, url = await result_queue.get()
    print(f'{url} finished at {result}')
 
asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 2):

I developed a library named octopus-api (https://pypi.org/project/octopus-api/), that enables you to rate limit and set the number of connections (parallel) calls to the endpoint using aiohttp under the hood. The goal of it is to simplify all the aiohttp setup needed.

Here is an example of how to use it, where the **get_ethereum** is the user-defined request function:

```py
from octopus_api import TentacleSession, OctopusApi
from typing import Dict, List

if __name__ == '__main__':
    async def get_ethereum(session: TentacleSession, request: Dict):
        async with session.get(url=request["url"], params=request["params"]) as response:
            body = await response.json()
            return body

    client = OctopusApi(rate=50, resolution="sec", connections=6)
    result: List = client.execute(requests_list=[{
        "url": "https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/ETH-EUR/candles?granularity=900&start=2021-12-04T00:00:00Z&end=2021-12-04T00:00:00Z",
        "params": {}}] * 1000, func=get_ethereum)
    print(result)
```

The TentacleSession works the same as how you write POST, GET, PUT and PATCH for aiohttp.ClientSession.

Let me know if it helps your issue related to rate limits and parallel calls.

Comment: Zero stars on github and 1 stack point. Very weird for what looks like a useful lib...

Answer (score 0):

As far as the question here regarding n requests being sent at the same time when gather() is called, the key is using create_task() with an `await asyncio.sleep(1.1)` before every call. Any task created with create_task is immediately run:

```
    for i in range(THREADS):
        await asyncio.sleep(1.1)
        tasks.append(
            asyncio.create_task(getData(session, q, ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(10))))
        )
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

The other issue of limiting # of simultaneous connections is also solved in the below example by using ClientSession() context in async_payload_wrapper and setting the connector with a limit.

With this setup I can run 25 coroutines (THREADS=25) that each loop over a queue of URLS and not violate a 25 concurrent connection rule:

```
async def send_request(session, url, routine):
    start_time = time.time()
    print(f"{routine}, sending request: {datetime.now()}")
    params = {
                'api_key': 'nunya',
                'url': '%s' % url, 
                'render_js': 'false',
                'premium_proxy': 'false', 
                'country_code':'us'
            }
    try:
        async with session.get(url='http://yourAPI.com',params=params,) as response:              
            data = await response.content.read()                     
            print(f"{routine}, done request: {time.time() - start_time} seconds")                    
        return data

    except asyncio.TimeoutError as e:    
        print('timeout---------------------')  
        errors.append(url)
    except aiohttp.ClientResponseError as e:
        print('request failed - Server Error')
        errors.append(url)
    except Exception as e:
        errors.append(url)

async def getData(session, q, test):
    while True:
        if not q.empty():
            url = q.get_nowait()
            resp = await send_request(session, url ,test)                      
            if resp is not None:
                processData(resp, test, url)
        else:
            print(f'{test} queue empty')
            break

async def async_payload_wrapper():
    tasks = []
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    for url in urls:
        await q.put(url)  


    async with ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=THREADS), timeout=ClientTimeout(total=61), raise_for_status=True) as session:    

        for i in range(THREADS):
            await asyncio.sleep(1.1)
            tasks.append(
                asyncio.create_task(getData(session, q, ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(10))))
            )
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    asyncio.run(async_payload_wrapper())
```