# How to collect results from async API call using pyspark udf?

Tags: python, pyspark, async-await, user-defined-functions

I am trying to write a pyspark udf that uses rate limiting via `asyncio` and `semaphore` in a PySpark workflow, but I am not able to make asynchronous calls work.

Using the following example, how can we make pyspark `withColumn` accept the output of an asynchronous UDF?

```python
from typing import Iterator
import pandas as pd
import asyncio
import aiohttp

from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, lit, col

# simple dataframe setup
pdf = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3], columns=["id"])
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

async def call_api_limit_wrap(session, value, limit):
    
    async with limit:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        pokemon_url = f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{value}'
        async with session.get(pokemon_url) as resp:
            pokemon = await resp.json()
            print(pokemon['name'])
            return pokemon['name']
    


@pandas_udf("string")
async def call_api_parallel(iterator: Iterator[pd.Series]) -> Iterator[pd.Series]:
    limit = asyncio.Semaphore(1) # 1 calls at a time
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        coroutines = [call_api_limit_wrap(session, id, limit) for id in iterator]
        yield await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)

# results as df
df = df.withColumn("name", call_api_parallel(df["id"]))
display(df)
```

Expected Output:

```
id | name
----------
 1   bulbasaur
 2   ivysaur
 3   venusaur
```

Error:

```
PythonException: 'TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable'. Full traceback below
```

Guides I tried:

- [pyspark pandas udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#pandas-udfs-aka-vectorized-udfs)
- [pyspark pandas udf - series](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#iterator-of-series-to-iterator-of-series)
- [SO answer on rate limiting in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48682456/1489422)
- [aiohttp for many requests](https://www.twilio.com/blog/asynchronous-http-requests-in-python-with-aiohttp)