# Java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have this error stack when I try to execute a set of Selenium Webdriver tests into Azure DevOps driver to remote server:

```
2023-03-08T21:06:46.9827484Z Running Test 66728 Mobile Web - Pick Task
2023-03-08T21:06:46.9827843Z Test Description https://dev.azure.com/Corporation/%20FootPrint/_workitems/edit/66728
2023-03-08T21:06:47.2244460Z Starting ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.41 (976ef12907ef9b413c2d929c043307b415d27b9e-refs/branch-heads/5563@{#737}) on port 35235
2023-03-08T21:06:47.2248489Z Only local connections are allowed.
2023-03-08T21:06:47.2273309Z Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
2023-03-08T21:06:47.2530381Z ChromeDriver was started successfully.
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3292859Z Mar 08, 2023 4:06:50 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3319163Z WARNING: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3320374Z java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3321045Z    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.abort(WebSocketHandler.java:92)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3321498Z    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.handleRead(WebSocketHandler.java:118)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3322255Z    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.AsyncHttpClientHandler.channelRead(AsyncHttpClientHandler.java:78)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3326071Z    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3334206Z    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3334813Z    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3335472Z    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3336148Z    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3336823Z    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:333)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3337255Z    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:454)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3337683Z    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3339980Z    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3340463Z    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3343324Z    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3344253Z    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3344757Z    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3345262Z    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3345959Z    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3346524Z    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3346956Z    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3347371Z    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3347781Z    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3348183Z    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3348555Z    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3349009Z    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3349522Z    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3350108Z    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3350574Z    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When I run the same code from my pc it's running fine. Do you know is it possible that WebDriver code is missing and for that reason I get this error?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Going through a bunch of different posts about this that showed up today.  The fix in most cases is to add a chromedriver option to your driver instance.  This is what got things working for me again.

Example:

```
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*")
```

Comment: While it works, if feels like potential security threat, is there specific origin that can be set instead of wildcard?

Comment: @MichaelBabich you're right. The way I'm using the ChromeDriver is to test an internal tool so it doesn't matter much. You're comment is very relevant. But, I don't have the answer... Sorry.

Comment: Just added that (Chrome V111). Chome started normally via Selenium but then got an error 500. `Could not start a new session. Response code 500. unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist. (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.` -> but it's still running

Answer (score 14):

The related Selenium issue is https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11750.

It will also work for Selenium 4.5+ if you upgrade to use the Java 11+ HTTP client, as described in https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/using-java11-httpclient/

Basically, add a dependency to

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-http-jdk-client</artifactId>
  <version>4.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and set the system property

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");
```

Comment: This works - thank you very much - but I am still confused why we need it?

Answer (score 8):

Using [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) ***v111.0*** this error message...

```
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3292859Z Mar 08, 2023 4:06:50 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
2023-03-08T21:06:50.3319163Z WARNING: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
```

...is the result of *`devtools_http_handler`* rejecting an incoming WebSocket connection from the http://localhost:xxxxx origin.

---

### Quick Solution

As the ChromeDriver [verbose log](https://groups.google.com/g/chromedriver-users/c/xL5-13_qGaA/m/cGk_5MvTAAAJ) suggests:

```
[32332:259:0214/190812.204658:ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(766)] Rejected an incoming WebSocket connection from the http://localhost:58642 origin. Use the command line flag --remote-allow-origins=http://localhost:58642 to allow connections from this origin or --remote-allow-origins=* to allow all origins.
```

A quick fix to this issue would be to add the argument *`--remote-allow-origins=*`* as follows:

- *Java*:

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of detailed discussions in:

- [org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection Selenium ChromeDriver and Chrome v111](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75741758/7429447)
- [Chrome 111 is not compatible with default HTTP Client](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11750)

Answer (score 4):

You should add the below code for issue :java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden and  websocket handler

```
            ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
            option.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");

            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
```

Comment: not solving the issue -

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs after update Chrome to version 111

Solution:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*","ignore-certificate-errors");

driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This error is fixed in Selenium version 4.9.0 with no workarounds needed for projects using JDK 8

Answer (score 1):

this is my sample test class:

```
public class AppTest

WebDriver driver ;
public static final String path = "/yourabsolutepath/chromedriver";
// im using linux, so no .exe, chromedrive is my driver not a folder.


public static void main(String[] args) {

}

@BeforeTest
public void doThisBefore(){
    ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
    option.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
    driver.get("https://selenium.dev/");
}
```

and this is a basic test :

```
    @Test
public void getTitle(){
    String title = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    Assert.assertEquals(title,"Selenium");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above and found that none of them worked. However, I am on chrome version 111.0.5563.64. I tried running the latest version of the chrome driver with chrome version 110 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Or just update the Selenide version to '6.12.2' if used Selenide in your project. This issue has already been fixed

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was solved after adding `<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>4.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```