# Eclipse error: Cannot invoke "org.asynchttpclient.ws.WebSocket.sendCloseFrame(int, String)" because "this.socket" is NULL

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am relatively new for Selenium.

My test automation project would be running without any issues yet at 13th. of March (3 days ago)

I did not change anything on the project itself.

However, starting from 14th. of March when I try to run the project:

[image]

I am getting the error:

```
Failure: 1 : Script desription
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.asynchttpclient.ws.WebSocket.sendCloseFrame(int, String)" because "this.socket" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.asynchttpclient.ws.WebSocket.sendCloseFrame(int, String)" because "this.socket" is null
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.close(NettyWebSocket.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection.close(Connection.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.quit(ChromiumDriver.java:192)
    at com.scriptDescription.StepDefinition.Step_DoSomething.before(Step_DoSomething.java:27)
Tests = 29
 : Successes = 28
 : Failures = 1
```

also see the screenshot:
[image]
The test script would not even start to execute.

the run would be stopped immediately:
[image]

The web browser is coming up but nothing is happening:
[image]

Can somebody share any ideas or any help, please.

Comment: Sounds like it's related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75718422/org-openqa-selenium-remote-http-connectionfailedexception-unable-to-establish-w/75741758#75741758

Comment: Thank you @pcalkins , your answer was also very helpful to get an understanding of what is the reason of the problem

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.asynchttpclient.ws.WebSocket.sendCloseFrame(int, String)" because "this.socket" is null
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.close(NettyWebSocket.java:116)
```

...implies that there was an issue with the ***asynchttpclient***.

---

### Details

The core issue is [Origin header is always sent from WebSocket client](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/9673) with ***Netty v4.x*** which is still being used by [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447). This issue is addressed in ***Netty v5.x***.

---

### Solution

The best solution would be to upgrade to [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11) [HTTP Client with Selenium 4.5.0 and beyond](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/using-java11-httpclient/)

However, a quick fix would be to add the argument --remote-allow-origins=* as follows:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection Selenium ChromeDriver and Chrome v111](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75741758/7429447)
- [Java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75740850/7429447)

Comment: Thank You, @undetected Selenium !!!  I added this line: "options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");"  exactly as per your advice (lines: ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); and WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options); are already there) and Voilà everything is working again.

Comment: Can it be related to the fact that my Chrome was updated few days ago

Comment: @Vladislav Ofcoarse, all these issues are related to the recent changes pushed in Chrome v111.x

Comment: Hi Team, now a month since I solved the issue, but it happened again today.  It is absolutely identical to how it was before same error. All the changes recommended by  @undetected Selenium are at place.  Can you give me any suggestions, please?

Comment: hello again. I am sorry to disturb, but may be you have any other suggestions why the issue is back after one month ?