# Unable to get Selenium v4.8.1 tests to run in docker container

Tags: java, docker, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, cucumber

I am unable to get the below selenium automation test to run inside a docker container:

```
package remoteTesting;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class chromeStandAloneTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), chromeOptions);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        System.out.println( driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Please see stack trace below:

```
/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-19.0.1/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=53394:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/shafiqahmedkhan/Downloads/remoteTesting/target/test-classes:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/Downloads/remoteTesting/target/classes:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/4.8.1/selenium-java-4.8.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-api/4.8.1/selenium-api-4.8.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/4.8.1/selenium-chrome-driver-4.8.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/com/google/auto/service/auto-service-annotations/1.0.1/auto-service-annotations-1.0.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/com/google/auto/service/auto-service/1.0.1/auto-service-1.0.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/com/google/auto/auto-common/1.2/auto-common-1.2.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/31.1-jre/guava-31.1-jre.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/failureaccess/1.0.1/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/listenablefuture/9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava/listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/3.12.0/checker-qual-3.12.0.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.11.0/error_prone_annotations-2.11.0.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.3/j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-chromium-driver/4.8.1/selenium-chromium-driver-4.8.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-json/4.8.1/selenium-json-4.8.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-devtools-v108/4.8.1/selenium-devtools-v108-4.8.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-devtools-v109/4.8.1/selenium-devtools-v109-4.8.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-devtools-v110/4.8.1/selenium-devtools-v110-4.8.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-devtools-v85/4.8.1/selenium-devtools-v85-4.8.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-edge-driver/4.8.1/selenium-edge-driver-4.8.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/4.8.1/selenium-firefox-driver-4.8.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-http/4.8.1/selenium-http-4.8.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/dev/failsafe/failsafe/3.3.0/failsafe-3.3.0.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-ie-driver/4.8.1/selenium-ie-driver-4.8.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-remote-driver/4.8.1/selenium-remote-driver-4.8.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/com/beust/jcommander/1.82/jcommander-1.82.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-buffer/4.1.87.Final/netty-buffer-4.1.87.Final.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-http/4.1.87.Final/netty-codec-http-4.1.87.Final.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec/4.1.87.Final/netty-codec-4.1.87.Final.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler/4.1.87.Final/netty-handler-4.1.87.Final.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.1.87.Final/netty-common-4.1.87.Final.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-classes-epoll/4.1.87.Final/netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.87.Final.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-classes-kqueue/4.1.87.Final/netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.87.Final.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/4.1.87.Final/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.87.Final.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-kqueue/4.1.87.Final/netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.87.Final.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-unix-common/4.1.87.Final/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.87.Final.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport/4.1.87.Final/netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-resolver/4.1.87.Final/netty-resolver-4.1.87.Final.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-api/1.22.0/opentelemetry-api-1.22.0.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-context/1.22.0/opentelemetry-context-1.22.0.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-exporter-logging/1.22.0/opentelemetry-exporter-logging-1.22.0.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-sdk-metrics/1.22.0/opentelemetry-sdk-metrics-1.22.0.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-sdk-logs/1.22.0-alpha/opentelemetry-sdk-logs-1.22.0-alpha.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-api-logs/1.22.0-alpha/opentelemetry-api-logs-1.22.0-alpha.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-sdk-common/1.22.0/opentelemetry-sdk-common-1.22.0.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-spi/1.22.0/opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-spi-1.22.0.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure/1.22.0-alpha/opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-1.22.0-alpha.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-sdk-trace/1.22.0/opentelemetry-sdk-trace-1.22.0.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-sdk/1.22.0/opentelemetry-sdk-1.22.0.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-semconv/1.22.0-alpha/opentelemetry-semconv-1.22.0-alpha.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/ous/jtoml/2.0.0/jtoml-2.0.0.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.12.22/byte-buddy-1.12.22.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/asynchttpclient/async-http-client/2.12.3/async-http-client-2.12.3.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/asynchttpclient/async-http-client-netty-utils/2.12.3/async-http-client-netty-utils-2.12.3.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-socks/4.1.60.Final/netty-codec-socks-4.1.60.Final.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler-proxy/4.1.60.Final/netty-handler-proxy-4.1.60.Final.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/4.1.60.Final/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.60.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-kqueue/4.1.60.Final/netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.60.Final-osx-x86_64.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.3/reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/netty/netty-reactive-streams/2.0.4/netty-reactive-streams-2.0.4.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/com/sun/activation/jakarta.activation/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-manager/4.8.1/selenium-manager-4.8.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-safari-driver/4.8.1/selenium-safari-driver-4.8.1.jar:/Users/shafiqahmedkhan/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-support/4.8.1/selenium-support-4.8.1.jar remoteTesting.chromeStandAloneTest
Mar 16, 2023 5:38:04 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.opentelemetry.OpenTelemetryTracer createTracer
INFO: Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Host info: host: '40eef246b475', ip: '172.17.0.2'
Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.49-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.17'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.49-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.17'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '13.2.1', java.version: '19.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}}]
Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:148)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor.execute(TracedCommandExecutor.java:51)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
    at remoteTesting.chromeStandAloneTest.main(chromeStandAloneTest.java:11)
```

I have tried restarting my docker container but still not able to get this to work.

Comment: It's important that you include enough information for people to reproduce your problem. Explaining how you start the web drivers hun and what happens there may help people answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using *`chromeOptions`* per say [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) and [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) combo presumably with the latest ***v111.x*** binaries you have to add the following argument:

```
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
```

Your effective code block will be:

```
package remoteTesting;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class chromeStandAloneTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), options=chromeOptions);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    System.out.println( driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection Selenium ChromeDriver and Chrome v111](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75741758/7429447)
- [Java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75740850/7429447)