# how to resolve error Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden in selenium 4

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager, selenium4

`Facing error while launching chrome driver.

WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

```
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();


    driver. manage().window().maximize();
```

Not working to launch chrome driver.`

Comment: Can you add the full `code` ? What `error` are you getting ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75678572/java-io-ioexception-invalid-status-code-403-text-forbidden)