# QAF | Selenium 4 is not working with QAF version 3.2.0

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium4, qaf

I'm not able to use Selenium 4 with the QAF version 3.2.0. Url is not opening after browser open (Blank page). Test is  working fine if I downgrade the selenium version to 3.141.59.

Note:
OS: Mac OSX
Java Version: 17
I have tried Selenium version 4.0.0, 4.1.2, 4.11.0

```
    <sourceVersion>1.8</sourceVersion>
    <targetVersion>1.8</targetVersion>
    <qaf.version>3.2.0</qaf.version>
    <selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>
    <selenium.version>4.0.0</selenium.version>
```

## ERROR:

> Aug 15, 2023 11:20:20 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
> INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
> Aug 15, 2023 11:20:20 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
> WARNING: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
> java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
> at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.abort(WebSocketHandler.java:92)
> at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.handleRead(WebSocketHandler.java:118)
> at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.AsyncHttpClientHandler.channelRead(AsyncHttpClientHandler.java:78)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:311)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:432)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
> at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
> at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
>
> ```
> Unable to create driver instance in 1st attempt with retry timeout of 0 seconds. You can check/set value of 'driver.init.retry.timeout' appropriately to set retry timeout on driver initialization failure.Unable to Create Driver Instance for chrome: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:62671/devtools/browser/a7e95bd5-94a4-4089-9c14-aa0d6e9427c0
> Build info: version: '4.0.0', revision: '3a21814679'
> System info: host: 'XXXXX-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:14e0:460c:5f80:9dbc%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '13.4', java.version: '17.0.8'
> Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
> Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 8.84 sec <<< FAILURE!
> Preparing For Shut Down...
> Result updator: Completed 1 Remaining 0 result to be update.
>
> Results :
>
> Failed tests:   Testing Google.com(com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.Scenario): Timed out after 0 seconds: Unable to create driver instance in 1st attempt with retry timeout of 0 seconds. You can check/set value of 'driver.init.retry.timeout' appropriately to set retry timeout on driver initialization failure.
>
> Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
>
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] Total time:  11.398 s
> [INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-15T23:20:21+10:00
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.9:test (default-test) on project qaf-blank-project-maven: There are test failures.
> [ERROR] 
> [ERROR] Please refer to /Users/Documents/Automation/qaf-blank-project-maven-master/test-results/15_Aug_2023_01_20_pm for the individual test results.
> [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR] 
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> [ERROR] 
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
> XXXX@XXXXX-MacBook-Pro qaf-blank-project-maven-master %
> ```

I have tried different versions of Selenium 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks duplicate of [Java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75678572/861594)

As a side note:

If you are using selenium 4, you should try latest version of selenium (4.11.0 as of today).
Below is selenium version compatibility for qaf:

- QAF 3.2.0 supports selenium 3.6.0 to 4.3.x
- QAF 4.0.0-RC1 supports selenium 4.0.0 to latest (4.11.0 as of today)

So if you are using selenium 4.11.0 you need to use QAF 4.0.0-RC1.

Comment: I got selenium 4.11.0 working using QAF 4.0.0-RC1 <qaf.version>4.0.0-RC1</qaf.version> <selenium.version>4.11.0</selenium.version>. I'm still not able to get QAF 3.2.0 working on Selenium 4.3.0 <qaf.version>3.2.0</qaf.version> <selenium.version>4.3.0</selenium.version>. Getting same above issue.